# Bind to ListView fieldName comes from resource

Tags: asp.net, listview, data-binding, localization, resources

I have a ListView, in its ItemTemplate I have bind a field like:
`<%#Eval("FiledName") %>`
But the FeildName itselfe comes from Resources, like:

`<asp:Localize Text="<%$ Resources: Resources, productnamefield %>" runat="server" />`

Now I need something like it:

`<%#Eval(<asp:Localize Text="<%$ Resources: Resources, productnamefield %>" runat="server" />) %>`

but it's not correct (has compile error)
How I combine these two?

Comment: Hmmmm. The only approach I can think of involves Reflection.

Comment: So it is compulsory to use "Eval" and you cannot bind your data to a web control (such as Literal) within your ListView?

Comment: Maybe it is possible sbhomra, but I don't know how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't something along the lines of this work:

```
protected void yourListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;

        Label filedName = e.Item.FindControl("FiledNameLabel") as Label;      

        //Get resource value
        string resourceValue = GetGlobalResourceObject("ResourceFile","productnamefield").ToString();  
        filedName.Text = drv[resourceValue].ToString();
    }
}
```

You will then use a Label in your ListView to display the value.